# cmd, avoiding the error "0x80070050: The file exists" when moving into Recycle bin

Tags: cmd.exe

I'm deleting a lot of files (around one million) on windows server 2012 via cmd.
I want them to go to the recycle bin, so I'm not using the `del` command, but the `recycle.exe` of CmdUtils.
The problem is that sometimes cmd stops with the message:

> ```
> An unexpected error is keeping you from deleting the file.
> If you continue to receive this error you can use the error code to search for help with this problem.
> ```

```
Error 0x80070050: The file exists.
```

and then I can choose among 'Try again' 'Skip' 'Cancel'

On CmdUtils/Recycle it seems I have only the `-f` option for avoiding the deleting confirmation message, but it doesn't work with the error I'm getting.
I've tried to contact CmdUtils developer, but no reply.

So, do you know another way for moving file into Recycle bin with the chance of automatically answer to that popup?
Thanks.

Comment: are you deleting an entire folder? or files in a directory? or how are you picking out these files?

Comment: I'm deleting some files on folders and subfolders

Answer (score 0):

The `/f` option doesn't avoid the confirmation message - all that does is ignore the `read-only` setting. What you're looking for is `/q`, which is quiet mode (suppresses prompts).

Depending on how you are selecting these files, I would probably use a combination of `DEL` and `RD`:

```
del /f /s /q yourfolder
rd /s /q yourfolder
```

This will avoid the recycling bin. If you clarify how you're selecting files for deletion (deleting entire folder, looping through a folder, etc.) I can give you a more specific method for getting rid of stuff.

Reference: [Del](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html), [RD](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I need those file to go into the recycle bin, that's why I wasn't using 'del'...

Comment: ah i misread the question; have you tried running `recycle.exe /?` to see if there were other options you should be using?

Comment: It's saying only "-f: Force recycle, no prompt for confermation", but I guess it doesn't mean the error I'm having...
So I think recycle.exe it's not the best way for my needs, the problem is that I have no idea on how to move files into Recycle bin and to avoid that error...

Comment: it looks like recycle.exe has a `/q` option for quiet - have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me... i got it on another link so, cant claim credit.. I will post credit as soon as I find it again...

1. In Powershell type wsl --shutdown
2. using regedit open the location \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss
3. Find the "DistributionName" parameters and change the data type from Ubuntu20.04TLS to Ubuntu-20.04

Good Luck

Comment: How is this answering the question?